# Serial Connection to Hokuyo from Master

Tags: urg-node, ros-kinetic, master, hokuyo, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently getting the error:

```
[ERROR] [1531729856.715593296]: Error connecting to Hokuyo: Could not open serial Hokuyo:
/dev/ttyACM0 @ 115200
could not open serial device.
```

Initially, after encountering this problem, I was able to resolve it by adding myself to the dialout list as suggested:
https://answers.ros.org/question/286646/error-connecting-to-hokuyo-could-not-open-serial-hokuyo/
I was able to view the data from the Hokuyo after doing this.

I am now trying to access the Hokuyo from a different machine.  On the drone (where the Hokuyo is connected), I changed ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP to match the PC.  On the PC, I then ran:

```
$ roscore
$ ssh drone-user@drone-IP
```

I am able to run '$ rostopic list' correctly.
However, after typing '$ rosrun urg_node urg_node', I receive the error mentioned above.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Justin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297487/serial-connection-to-hokuyo-from-master/) by [Justin-RR2-IP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36487/justin-rr2-ip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have managed to fix the error, it was caused by a large discrepancy in time between the PC and the drone.
Connecting both devices to the internet and synchronizing their times was enough to resolve the issue.
Initially, I tried using the 'chrony' package for Ubuntu but I was unable to synchronize the times using this.

Any suggestions on how to get the drone to synchronize its time to match the PC's would be greatly appreciated!

---

Originally posted by [Justin-RR2-IP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36487/justin-rr2-ip/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0